# How to lazy load images in webview android

Tags: android, webview, lazy-loading

How to load images in webview as background i.e lazy load images in webview android. Right now while loading a url in my app which uses webview on scrolling images not load instantly which causes UI slide up/down each time any images loads. How can I load images in background with placing a placeholder while the images not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

the webpage which sould be shown, have to provide the dimension of the image. Otherwise you have no chance to guess the dimension for your placeholder. If the dimension is providede. the Webview will automatical reserve the space for the image. (works like any browser)

Comment: Like I'm getting this image tag "<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1133" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Redmi-4-first-sale-numbers.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="305" />"
In which there is specified width and height but webview sometimes take some times show image and load images. So how can I place a holder for this image tag.